# Binding WPF control visibility using multiple variables from the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing a WPF user control which displays a dynamically generated TabControl with multiple pages, each page in turn contains a list of dynamically generated controls (TextBox, Checkbox etc).

I want to set the visibility of the TextBox, CheckBox controls based on whether the user has permission to view them or not. This permission is a combination of a value on each controls ViewModel ('VisiblyBy') and also a property of the overall UserControl ViewModel ('UserRole'). I'm just getting started on WPF but the standard method seems to be to use a ValueConvertor - however I don't understand how I could write one which would combine/access the different properties (VisiblyBy and UserRole) as they exist at different levels in my ViewModel hierary.

Here is part of the XAML where I bind to the ViewModel:

```html
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding VariableData.Pages}" SelectedIndex="0">
<!-- this is the header template-->
   <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            
<!-- this is the tab content template-->
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel>
        <ListBox  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Variables}"
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}">
        </ListBox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
           <Button Content="Cancel" />
               <Button Content="Submit" 
                       Command="{Binding DataContext.CommitChangesCommand, 
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                   AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I would also need to extend the number of variables that control visibility in the future as it would also depend where in the application it is used from.

Comment: You can try IMultiValueConverter and use Multibinding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try IMultiValueConverter and use Multibinding.

```
<Window x:Class="ItemsControl_Learning.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemsControl_Learning"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="conv" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Test">
        <Button.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                <Binding  Path="Role" />
                <Binding Path="OtherProp" />                   
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.Visibility>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }       
}

class MainViewModel
{
    private string role;
    public string Role
    {
        get { return role; }
        set { role = value; }
    }

    private string otherProp;
    public string OtherProp
    {
        get { return otherProp; }
        set { otherProp = value; }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Role = "Admin";
        OtherProp = "Fail";
    }
}

class VisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0].ToString().Equals("Admin") && values[1].ToString().Equals("Pass"))
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the `Convert(...)` method, the order of the different inputs in the `values` array is the same order as in the `MultiBinding.Bindings` collection.

In this example `values[0]` contains the `Role` property and `values[1]` will be `OtherProp` because that is the order they got inserted in XAML

Comment: After many hours of reading and trying other solutions I ended up writing a MultiValueConverter and it works great so far - thanks a million.

Comment: I ended up providing two answers...but I truly see why this is a great solution. +1 from me. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Bind to a composite property which holds the status instead without the need for a converter.

---

I would create a composite property on the ViewModel called `IsAuthorized` and just bind to **that property**. For it always return the **current** status when the other properties are set.

How?

To accomplish the **composite property** the `Role` and `IsOther` properties also call `PropertyChange` on the `IsAuthorized` property; which always keeps the status fresh on the page.

```
public Visiblity IsAuthorized
{
   get { return  (Role == "Admin" && OtherProp == "True") 
                     ? Visbility.Visible 
                     : Visibility.Hidden; }

}

 // When a value changes in Role or OtherProp fire PropertyChanged for IsAuthorized. 
public string Role
{
   get { return_Role;}
   set { _Role = value; 
         PropertyChanged("Role");
         PropertyChanged("IsAuthorized");
       }
}

public string OtherProp
{
   get { return_OtherProp;}
   set { _OtherProp = value; 
         PropertyChanged("OtherProp");
         PropertyChanged("IsAuthorized");
       }
}
```

People seem to think that one has to only bind to a specific property(ies), but why make your life harder when a simply call to PropertyChanged with a composite property will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried it out but I couldn't figure out how to access a property of both the top level ViewModel and of the actual data model that was bound to the control I am trying to change the visibility on.

Comment: contd...

Tth 'value' parameter pass to my Convert() method was bound to my ViewModel, so I had half the data. I thought that I could use the ConverterParameter to access my data model object (or even just the VisibleBy property that I needed - however I couldn't get it to work and the more I read about the ConverterParameter it doesn't seem very easy.

Comment: @canice I have provided a secondary answer; is it a good one for what you are doing...maybe. At least you have options. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here is the MultiValueConverter I ended up using - note I need add in better error checking on the object array but the idea works.

```
public class AccessLevelToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        var viewModel = (VariableDataViewModel)values[0];
        var item = (VariableDataItem)values[1];

        visibility = viewModel.IsVariableVisible(item);

        return visibility;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack( object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And this is the corresponding XAML:

```
<Grid.Visibility>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{p:AccessLevelToVisibilityConverter}" >
      <Binding Path="DataContext",  
               RelativeSource="{RelativeSource 
                                AncestorType=UserControl}" />
      <Binding Path="." />
   </MultiBinding>
</Grid.Visibility>
```

I need to apply it to multiple DataTemplates so I guess the way to do that is through a style.

Answer (score 0):

What if we transferred the Inversion of Control method to check security/visibility away from the Converter and on to the actual object?

To do that we would need to have the entity instance report its visibility *without the need of a converter* but still use the VM to provide *authorization* in a `IOC` dependency injected method in a two part system.

---

Let me explain by code:

Using the motif of access levels

```
public enum SecurityLevels
{
    publicLevel = 0,
    userLevel,
    adminLevel
}
```

The VM will still contain the current Security level (*ultimately based on the actual users login role?*) along with a method to report if an accessing instance has the right to access/be shown for the current level. This will be defined in an interface which the VM has to adhere to named `IAuthorize`.

```
public interface IAuthorize
{
    SecurityLevels CurrentLevel { get; set; }
    bool GetAuthorization(IAmIAuthorized instance);
}
```

The `IAmIAuthorized` (*Am-I-Authorized*) interface will be required of every entity to be shown and is the second part of the two-part security. Notice the Dependency Injection function `DetermineAuthorizationFunc` which will eventually be supplied from the VM via Dependency Injection:

```
public interface IAmIAuthorized
{
   SecurityLevels Level { get; }

   Visibility IsVisible { get; }

   bool IsAuthorized { get; }

   Func<IAmIAuthorized, bool> DetermineAuthorizationFunc { get; set; }
}
```

Now the entity object if trusted can derive `IAmIAuthorzied` and report visibility via the `DetermineAuthorizationFunc` or we can create a wrapper or a derived class with the interface. In any case, every entity *to be shown* has to have the above interface in one form or another and call `DetermineAuthorizationFunc`.

Our Xaml becomes easier for we know that the entities' `IsVisible` is doing its job and returning a `Visibility` based on the current VM state with its pre-req state.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" />
```

With that we have moved the IOC away from a Conversion method and into the VM.

Here is an actual implementation of the OP's `VariableDataItem` class in this situation:

```
public class VariableDataItem  : IAmIAuthorized
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SecurityLevels Level { get; set; }

    public Func<IAmIAuthorized, bool> DetermineAuthorizationFunc { get; set; }

    public bool IsAuthorized
    {
        get { return DetermineAuthorizationFunc != null && 
                     DetermineAuthorizationFunc(this); }
    }

    public Visibility IsVisible
    {
        get { return IsAuthorized ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden; }
    }    
}
```

With code from the VM

```
Holdings = new List<VariableDataItem>()
{
    new VariableDataItem() {Name = "Alpha", DetermineAuthorizationFunc = GetAuthorization, Level = SecurityLevels.publicLevel  },
    new VariableDataItem() {Name = "Beta",  DetermineAuthorizationFunc = GetAuthorization, Level = SecurityLevels.userLevel    },
    new VariableDataItem() {Name = "Gamma", DetermineAuthorizationFunc = GetAuthorization, Level = SecurityLevels.adminLevel   }
};
```

And the IOC dependency injected method:

```
public bool GetAuthorization(IAmIAuthorized instance)
{
    return (int)instance.Level <= (int)CurrentLevel; 
}
```

---

Under that system if the current state is `userLevel` our list will only show Alpha (which is public) and Beta (which is User) but not Gamma which is admin only:

[image]

Admin can see all:

[image]